# Transactional inserts across table partitions

Tags: c#, azure, azure-storage, azure-table-storage

I am storing an entity in two Azure Storage tables.  The data is identical in both tables except that the `RowKey` and `PartitionKey` are different (this is for querying purposes).

**Problem**

When inserting into these tables, I need the operation to be transactional - the data must only commit if both inserts are successful.

`CloudTable.ExecuteBatch(..)` only works when entities belong to the same partition.

Is there no other way of doing this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Short answer:

Unfortunately no. Entity batch transactions are only supported for just 1 table at a time and [some other restrictions](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsazure/dd894038.aspx).

Long answer:

We too have faced similar problem where we had to insert data across multiple tables. One thing we have done is we have tried to implement some kind of `eventual consistency`. Instead of writing data directly into the table, we write that data in a queue and have a background worker role process that data. Once the data is written in the queue, we assume that data will eventually be persisted (there's a caching engine also involved which is updated with the latest data here as well so that application can get the latest data). Background worker role keeps on retrying inserts (using `InsertOrReplace` semantic instead of just `Insert` semantic) and once all the data is written, we simply delete the message from the queue.